# Entered email override SecureRandom email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, email

[image]

**Approach #1**

```
Send email reminder to <%= email_field_tag :email,  nil, placeholder: 'Enter Email', class: "send-email" %> # :email belongs to the users table
```

**Approach #2**

```
Send email reminder to <%= f.email_field :default_email, class: "send-email", placeholder: "Enter Email" %> # :default_email belongs to the challenges table. The point of this is to try something in the create process like current_user.email == @challenge.default_email
```

The user is then redirected to `signup url`

[image]

If a user signs up via Facebook a random email is generated so that he can get through the validation process: `user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com"`

**user.rb**

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     # Sets 60 day auth token
     oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("125402372971231236229929", "ee917abf2e8f1c98274cdafssadffddffaebb1346f4")
     new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info auth.credentials.token

     new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
     new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds

    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = new_access_token # auth.credentials.token <- your old token. Not needed anymore.
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.password = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
      user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com" unless user.email.present?
      user.activated = true
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

But how can we make the email the user inputted in the **challenges/create.html.erb** form seen above override the SecureRandom email?

**users_controller**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
      deadline = session.delete(:challenge_deadline)
      committed = session.delete(:challenge_committed)
      date_started = session.delete(:challenge_date_started)
      order = session.delete(:challenge_order)
      days_challenged = session.delete(:challenge_days_challenged)
      why = session.delete(:challenge_why)
      conceal = session.delete(:challenge_conceal)
      @user.challenges.create(action: action, deadline: deadline, why: why, conceal: conceal, date_started: date_started, committed: committed, days_challenged: days_challenged)
      end
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**challenges_controller**

```
  before_action :update_user_email, if: proc {|c| c.current_user.present? && c.params[:email].present? }

  def create
    @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)
    if params[:step] == '2'
      if current_user == nil
        # If there is no user, store values to the session.
        session[:challenge_action] = challenge_params[:action]
        session[:challenge_committed] = challenge_params[:committed]
        session[:challenge_deadline] = [params["challenge"]["deadline(3i)"], params["challenge"]["deadline(2i)"], params["challenge"]["deadline(1i)"]].join('/')
        session[:challenge_date_started] = [params["challenge"]["date_started(3i)"], params["challenge"]["date_started(2i)"], params["challenge"]["date_started(1i)"]].join('/')
        session[:challenge_order] = challenge_params[:order]
        session[:challenge_days_challenged] = challenge_params[:days_challenged]
        session[:challenge_why] = challenge_params[:why]
        session[:challenge_conceal] = challenge_params[:conceal]
        redirect_to signup_path
      else
        @challenge = current_user.challenges.build(challenge_params)
        @challenge.save
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    else
      respond_modal_with @challenge
    end
  end

private

  def update_user_email
    email = params[:email]
    current_user.update_attribute(:email, email)
  end
```

**sessions_controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def facebook
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def create
    assign_email(cookies[:challenges_email])
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    assign_email(cookies[:challenges_email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      assign_email(cookies[:challenges_email])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == 'nil' ? forget(user) : remember(user)
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:info] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Why won’t you just introduce a default value for `email` field, setting it to this `SecureRandom` _before user creation_ and make it editable field?

Comment: @mudasobwa a user doesn't have to add his email if he is signing in through facebook, but if he decided to add it anywhere in the signup process like in the challenges creation form then I want that to override `SecureRandom` somehow. I'm confused with how do I store user `email` in session for `nil` user and then save it upon create if facebook. I showed my work for how I stored challenge attributes.

Comment: Have you tried -- `session[:reminder_email] = params[:email]` or take a look at the params you have in your `challenges_controller` `create` method to see what it is called? If it's part of the form that's submitted, it should be there. Then you can check for its presence at the point where you are setting the `SecureRandom` email and use it instead if it is there (remember to delete it...).

Comment: Save the email in the session. When the facebook auth is complete you will have a chance to update the user's email to whatever is stored in session.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. Okay so I add `session[:reminder_email] = params[:email]`. Then I make it something like this: `user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com unless :reminder.email.present?"` Sorry just confused by the last part of your comment

Comment: How would you save it to the session @maxpleaner?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com you're already doing it in Challenges#create

Comment: So `session[:reminder_emaill] = params[:email]` like Joseph suggested @maxpleaner? "you will have a chance to update the user's email to whatever is stored" - How do I stop SecureRandom from overriding user's stored email? Doesn't create challenge occur before create user and therefore SecureRandom will override otherwise I would use `user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com" unless user.email.present?`

Comment: first, if those are your actual `Koala::Facebook::OAuth` secret keys/ids, you need to change them immediately. second, post the code that invokes `User.from_omniauth` and indicate which controller it is

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. They're aren't ;)

Comment: OK, good! -- but post the code that calls that method and explain how we get there.

Comment: I realized that this question is too buff. So I broke it down into smaller problems. I'm working on solving this one now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142241/how-to-store-email-in-session-and-save-upon-create-to-new-user. I don't love using cookies and the other answer doesn't work so I'm still struggling @Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We talked about setting it as a cookie in another question. If you're taking that approach, you could pass the cookie to a method. Something like what is discussed in this question:

```
 before_create :set_user_email

 def assign_email(email)
   @email = email
 end

 def set_user_email
   self.email = @email
 end
```

then in the controller action where you have access to the cookie:

```
 assign_email(cookies[:challenge_email])
```

Comment: I put the first chunk of code in the user model and in the from_omniauth method I have `user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com" unless user.email.present?`. I put the second chunk of code in the challenges_controller create action and in the users_controller create action. Is this what you intended? I can't get it to work yet. Email shows `nil` upon user create

Comment: `assign_email` should be in the users controller. the rest should be in `user.rb`.

Comment: Did that. Part of problem was you had `[:challenge_email]` so I switched it to  `[:challenges_email]`, but still user = nil. How should I have it in the omniauth method? I've been trying different things like `user.email = @email`

Comment: Where should `assign_email(cookies[:challenges_email])` go? I put it right beneath `@user = User.new(user_params)` in the challenges_controller create action

Comment: Make sure assign_email is being called before you get to from_omniauth. Actually--at the beginning of `from_omniauth` check to see if you have access to @email by `puts @email`. If you do not, then assign_email hasn't run yet to set the variable.

Comment: Hey I updated question with sessions_controller. I have to put it in create for facebook I realize now, but still it doesn't work. I'll try puts to gain more info

Comment: I thought I'd have it with this: `def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if cookies[:challenges_email].present?
      user.email = cookies[:challenges_email]
    end` in sessions_controller, but no.

Comment: yeah--you can't look up the user by the email when you don't have an email set for the user

Comment: Yea that's weird. I built omniauth-facebook using railscasts. It works tho the `find_by` to create a new user

Comment: weird. to create? find_by would be to look up an existing user.

Comment: I think because this method triggers first? `def self.from_omniauth(auth)` and then user is created and then that controller action does the rest for facebook signup

Comment: I finally got it. I can cry. This coding business can be tough work. I've been at this problem for days. You were such a huge help! Thank you! I needed to put `if cookies[:challenges_email].present? user.email = cookies[:challenges_email] end` in `def facebook`. For some reason def create goes into def facebook

Answer (score 1):

@joseph had answered it pretty simple but i think you can just get email in the field by setting it in the controller like; 
`User.new(:email => "email you want to show in the field")`
 no need to pass nil user object pass a new object.

And in the view file it will shown in email field with

```
Send email reminder to <%= f.email_field :email, class: "send-email", placeholder: "Enter Email" %>
```

Comment: Which controller and where do I put that first line of code? The goal isn't to get the"email you want to show in the field". The goal of the question is to not let SecureRandom override entered email. Hope that clarifies things. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yeah right its overriding because of the code : `user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com" unless user.email.present?` as in omniauth function its not accessing the entered email in the form. comment out this line and this will work fine. plus if you want to display securerandom in case of no email then you have to add a check with the email field to not change text if its already filled.

Comment: @anthony There is another possibility you are not getting email params right like try params[:user][:email] instead of params[:email] in update_user_email method.