# How to store email in session and save upon create to new user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

A `nil` user can create a `challenge` before signing up.

**challenges/_form view**

```
<%= text_field :action %>
<% if current_user %>
  Send reminder to <%= text_field_tag :email, current_user.email %>
<% else %>
  Send reminder to <%= email_field_tag :email,  nil, placeholder: 'Enter Email' %>
<% end %>
```

How can I save to session `:email` & `:action` upon challenge create? I got `:action` to work.

**challenges_controller**

```
def create
  if current_user == nil
    session[:challenge_action] = challenge_params[:action]
    session[:user_email] = params[:email] # Email is an attribute of user. A user has_many challenges 
    redirect_to signup_path
  end
end

def update_user_email
  email = params[:email]
  current_user.update_attribute(:email, email)
end
```

**heroku logs**

```
Processing by ChallengesController#create as HTML
2016-03-21T21:19:48.873239+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B5S4YGBOcnb+GYewM5lDUB/nBOedaIrpVpOOlQuoT4E9NFDBsj/x3ltBG2OXNEt+Z8jgRVuhzHz8eDqNjv0GkRg==", "challenge"=>{"action"=>"Run a 5K", "send_email"=>["sun", ""]}, "email"=>"test@gmail.com", "button"=>""}
```

Once the user is created I want the stored email to be saved as the user's email, but yet the `:email` says `nil`:

```
=> #<User id: 48, name: "Anthony Galli", email: nil,
=> #<Challenge id: 67, action: "Run a 5K"
```

**users_controller**

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
    email = session.delete(:user_email)
    @user.challenges.create(action: action, email: email)
  end  
end
```

**users/new view**

```
# No email_field is included. The goal is that it is not necessary since email was included with challenge form.
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

### BY REQUEST

**users_controller full**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy]

  def index
    @users, @alphaParams = User.alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:pagination_class => "pagination-centered"}){|user| user.name}
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @past_challenges = @user.challenges.publish.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline < Date.current if challenge.deadline.present? }
    @past_challenges_by_years = @past_challenges.group_by { |t| t.deadline.year }
    @present_oneshot_challenges = @user.challenges.publish.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline == Date.current if challenge.deadline.present? }
    @present_habit_challenges_today = @user.challenges.publish.unaccomplished.committed_for_today.order(:order).select{ |challenge| challenge.date_started <= Date.tomorrow if challenge.date_started.present? }
    @present_habit_challenges_not_today = @user.challenges.publish.unaccomplished.noncommitted_for_today.select{ |challenge| challenge.date_started <= Date.tomorrow if challenge.date_started.present? }
    @future_challenges = @user.challenges.unaccomplished.publish.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline > Date.current if challenge.deadline.present? }
    @future_challenges_by_years = @future_challenges.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_year }
    @inspirations = @user.inspirations.publish
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.email = session.delete(:user_email)
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
      deadline = session.delete(:challenge_deadline)
      committed = session.delete(:challenge_committed)
      date_started = session.delete(:challenge_date_started)
      order = session.delete(:challenge_order)
      days_challenged = session.delete(:challenge_days_challenged)
      why = session.delete(:challenge_why)
      conceal = session.delete(:challenge_conceal)
      if deadline.present?
        @user.challenges.create(action: action, deadline: deadline, why: why, conceal: conceal, date_started: date_started, committed: committed, days_challenged: days_challenged, email: email)
      end
      @user.send_welcome_email
      log_in @user
      redirect_to tutorial_url
      flash[:info] = 'Welcome to Live to Challenge!'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to root_url
      flash[:success] = "Settings updated"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private


    def user_params
      if params[:conceal] = true
        params.require(:user).permit(:time_zone, :name, :email, :tag_list, :password, :conceal, inspirations_attributes: [:name, :tag_list, :conceal], activities_attributes: [:conceal, :action, :trackable_id, :trackable_type])
      else
        params[:user][:conceal] = false
        params.require(:user).permit(:time_zone, :name, :image, :tag_list, :email, :password, inspirations_attributes: [:name, :tag_list], activities_attributes: [:action, :trackable_id, :trackable_type])
      end
    end

  # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please sign in first"
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

**challenges_controller full**

```
class ChallengesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_challenge, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :challenging, :mark_accomplished, :mark_completed, :create_freebie, :like]
  before_action :update_user_email, if: proc {|c| c.current_user.present? && c.params[:email].present? }
  respond_to :html, :json

  def new_freebie
    @challenge = current_user.challenges.find(params[:id])
    @challenge.freebie_date = Date.yesterday
    respond_modal_with @challenge
  end

  def create_freebie
    @challenge.update(challenge_params)
    @challenge.freebie = @challenge.freebie + 1
    @challenge.save
    respond_modal_with @challenge, location: root_path
    flash[:alert] = 'Freebie added'
  end

  def sort 
    params[:order].each do |id, order|
    Challenge.where(id: id).update_all(order: order) 
  end 
    render nothing: true 
  end

  def mark_accomplished
    @challenge.update(accomplished: true, :dont_set_tag_owner => true)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render :nothing => true }
      end
  end

  def completed
    @challenge = current_user.challenges.find(params[:challenge_id])
    @challenge.update(accomplished: true)
    @challenge.deadline = Date.current
    respond_modal_with @challenge, location: root_path
  end

  def index
    @past_challenges = current_user.challenges.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline < Date.current if challenge.deadline.present? }
    @past_challenges_by_years = @past_challenges.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_year }
    @present_oneshot_challenges = current_user.challenges.unaccomplished.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline == Date.current if challenge.deadline.present? }
    @present_habit_challenges_today = current_user.challenges.unaccomplished.committed_for_today.order(:order).select{ |challenge| challenge.date_started <= Date.tomorrow if challenge.date_started.present? }
    @present_habit_challenges_not_today = current_user.challenges.unaccomplished.noncommitted_for_today.select{ |challenge| challenge.date_started <= Date.tomorrow if challenge.date_started.present? }
    @future_challenges = current_user.challenges.unaccomplished.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline > Date.current if challenge.deadline.present? }
    @future_challenges_by_years = @future_challenges.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_year }
  end

  def show
    @challenge_to_deadline = current_user.challenges.group_by {|i| i.deadline} if current_user
    @notable = @challenge
    @notes = @notable.notes
    @note = Note.new
    @commentable = @challenge
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @correct_user = current_user.challenges.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def challenging
    @challenge = Challenge.new
  end

  def new
    @challenge = Challenge.new
    respond_modal_with @challenge, location: root_path
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)
    if params[:step] == '2'
      if current_user == nil
        # If there is no user, store the lifetime values to the session.
        session[:challenge_action] = challenge_params[:action]
        session[:challenge_committed] = challenge_params[:committed]
        session[:challenge_deadline] = [params["challenge"]["deadline(3i)"], params["challenge"]["deadline(2i)"], params["challenge"]["deadline(1i)"]].join('/')
        session[:challenge_date_started] = [params["challenge"]["date_started(3i)"], params["challenge"]["date_started(2i)"], params["challenge"]["date_started(1i)"]].join('/')
        session[:challenge_order] = challenge_params[:order]
        session[:challenge_days_challenged] = challenge_params[:days_challenged]
        session[:challenge_why] = challenge_params[:why]
        session[:challenge_conceal] = challenge_params[:conceal]
        session[:user_email] = params[:email]
        redirect_to signup_path
      else
        @challenge = current_user.challenges.build(challenge_params)
        if @challenge.conceal == true
          @challenge.save
          redirect_to root_path
          if @challenge.date_started.present?
            flash[:info] = 'Habit Challenge secretly saved! Click "Strike 1" upon incompleting a day.'
          else
            flash[:info] = 'Goal Challenge secretly saved! Click checkmark upon completing it.'
          end
        elsif
          @challenge.save
          track_activity @challenge
          redirect_to root_path
          if @challenge.date_started.present?
            flash[:info] = 'Habit Challenge saved! Click "Strike 1" upon incompleting a day.'
          else
            flash[:info] = 'Goal Challenge saved! Click checkmark upon completing it.'
          end
        else
          respond_modal_with @challenge
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @challenge.update(challenge_params)
    flash[:info] = 'Challenge updated'
    respond_modal_with @challenge, location: root_path
  end

  def destroy
    @challenge.destroy
    respond_modal_with @challenge, location: root_path
  end

  def like
    @challenge_like = current_user.challenge_likes.build(challenge: @challenge)
    if @challenge_like.save
      @challenge.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
    end  
      redirect_to(:back)
  end

private
  def update_user_email
    email = params[:email]
    current_user.update_attribute(:email, email)
  end

  def set_challenge
    @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
  end

  def challenge_params
    params.require(:challenge).permit(
      :default_email,
      :action,
      :why, 
      :like, 
      :deadline, 
      :accomplished, 
      :tag_list, 
      :conceal,
      :archive,
      :trigger,
      :missed_days,
      :target, 
      :reward,
      :order,
      :date_started,
      :date_ended,
      :days_challenged,
      :completed_at,
      :freebie,
      :freebie_date, 
      :send_email => [],
      :committed => [])
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :challenges
  has_many :authentications
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :challenges, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, format: { with: /\A[a-z\sA-Z]+\z/,
    message: "only allows letters" }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, unless: -> { from_omniauth? }
  has_secure_password

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     # Sets 60 day auth token
     oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("154dsaf203729762293929", "ee917abf2esdf8f1c98274cdfasdfdsaebb1346f4")
     new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info auth.credentials.token

     new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
     new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds

    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = new_access_token # auth.credentials.token <- your old token. Not needed anymore.
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.password = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
      #I commented out below line so it doesn't override email saved with challenge form
      #user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com" unless user.email.present?
      user.activated = true
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def self.koala(auth)
    access_token = auth['token']
    facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
    facebook.get_object("me?fields=name,picture")
  end

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

private 

    def from_omniauth? 
      provider && uid 
    end

      # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email 
      self.email = email.downcase unless from_omniauth? 
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
      self.activated = true
    end
end
```

For Chewy: **rails c**

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-22 14:58:07 -0400
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZuWflxk9Vljppe9cRUdzzKsfzcekWqNvpo1HnTfVVdiZR9kruqDQnZDXHyohcitGUpVJchGpartqG+hc9450RA==", "user"=>{"name"=>"afdsdfsasafddfsa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "time_zone"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"}, "button"=>""}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("time_zone", "name", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at", "activation_digest", "activated") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["time_zone", "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"], ["name", "afdsdfsasafddfsa"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$jzIDcHvKD1hwZMvfSQx4x.D1qtif.c53bOSPTsaYd9SsG9MvoADBS"], ["created_at", "2016-03-22 18:58:08.038359"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-22 18:58:08.038359"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$.WDl3Zqz2VxcbuuWAOgWE.awi7EZ1DalAeFA79B.AUpg0h0Xmb9t6"], ["activated", "t"]]
   (1.9ms)  COMMIT
cookie@gmail.com
cookie@gmail.com
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "challenges" ("committed", "action", "deadline", "why", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["committed", nil], ["action", "Meditate"], ["deadline", "2016-03-22"], ["why", ""], ["user_id", 32], ["created_at", "2016-03-22 18:58:08.176075"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-22 18:58:08.176075"]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
cookie@gmail.com
cookie@gmail.com
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (19.9ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "email" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["email", "cookie@gmail.com"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-22 18:58:08.194324"], ["id", 32]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "challenges" SET "committed" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "challenges"."id" = $3  [["committed", nil], ["updated_at", "2016-03-22 18:58:08.237871"], ["id", 40]]
   (1.8ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.6ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.3ms)

UserMailer#welcome_email: processed outbound mail in 79.3ms

Sent mail to cookie@gmail.com (1561.2ms)
```

**Chewy's users_controller**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
      puts cookies[:challenges_email]
      if cookies[:challenges_email].present?
        @user.email = cookies[:challenges_email]
      end
      puts cookies[:challenges_email]
      if deadline.present?
        @user.challenges.create(action: action, deadline: deadline, why: why, conceal: conceal, date_started: date_started, committed: committed, days_challenged: days_challenged)
      end
      puts cookies[:challenges_email]
      if cookies[:challenges_email].present?
        @user.email = cookies[:challenges_email]
      end
      puts cookies[:challenges_email]
      @user.email = cookies[:challenges_email]
      @user.save
      @user.send_welcome_email
      log_in @user
      redirect_to tutorial_url
      flash[:info] = 'Welcome to Live to Challenge!'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Show the sign up form. The email should come from it. And where is the @user in your UsersController#create action from ?

Comment: Also, show the action where the @user, which is in the sign up form, comes  from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to set a cookie when they submit the challenges form and then check for the existence of that cookie:

```
unless cookies[:challenges_email].present?
  cookies[:challenges_email] = {
    value: params[:email],
    expires: 1.year.from_now
  }
end
```

Then on the page where the user signs up, check for the existence of the cookie (inside user `create` action):

```
if cookies[:challenges_email].present?
   @user.email = cookies[:challenges_email]
end
```

If you want to do this for additional fields you would set an additional cookie as they are meant to be key-value pairs.

Comment: Thanks Todd for the help! I updated "users/new view". I want to do without the `:email` line in the form altogether and store email to session and then save to new user upon create.

Comment: this will allow you to do that, you'll just need to use the cookie to set the value of the email when you create the user. added an edit for clarity.

Comment: I put the first chunk of code in the challenge_controller create action. Was that wrong because it didn't work? user email still `nil` upon create :/

Comment: after creating a challenge, verify that your cookie is being set. open up the chrome dev tools, click `Resources` and then in the sidebar, click `Cookies`. You should see your cookie in the list with a non-nil value.

Comment: Did you intend to use `[:challenges_email]` or `[:email]` or `[:user_email]` because maybe that's throwing me off. And if you did intend to use `[:challenges_email]` am I suppose to still leave in challenges_controller: `session[:user_email] = params[:email]`

Comment: No cookies Todd :/

Comment: Where are you setting that cookie? Are you setting it when you create a challenge? If a challenge saves, this code should run: `cookies[:challenges_email] = {
    value: params[:email],
    expires: 1.year.from_now
  }` Immediately following a challenge saving, you should be able to check for the cookie and find it to be present

Comment: Actually it is setting the cookie :] I didn't click on the dropdown menu of cookies. But upon creating the user the email remains `nil`.

Comment: `irb(main):006:0> User.last
=> #<User id: 61, name: "Anthony Galli", email: nil, provider: "facebook", uid: "516541231230741839117", oauth_token: "CAAV49ggR3ikB12312312312213AFwTKG0DZCfTRh3ftLEK1CL8wps6FRdU38Jys...", oauth_expires_at: "2016-05-21 15:51:02", created_at: "2016-03-22 18:27:57", updated_at: "2016-03-22 18:28:47", password_digest: "$2a$10$ggJOSZt9I1232132130DPhTYdzIMGVOnmWe0X3wsZAN4QFN3GIac...", remember_digest: nil, admin: false, activation_digest: "$2a$10$OFUSt6vg1123212321218GyAK.fX7jLhuZma0ZXEJakDZJnQHhypAf...", activated: true, activated_at: nil>`

Comment: So it's setting the cookie. Now you need to make sure you're assigning the cookie value to the user. In the user create action `puts cookies[:challenges_email]` to make sure it's there, after if `@user.save` add `@user.email = cookies[:challenges_email]` and then `@user.save` again. We can do this without saving twice but this is easy way to debug / find the problem.

Comment: Okay I did puts. Interesting thing is it is sending welcoming email to the cookie email address, but not saving it to user.

Comment: you aren't setting the email in your code. re-read my last email. not just puts. you need to actually set the email for @user and then save.

Comment: the call should be to `cookies[:challenges_email]` or whatever you set it as...but you need the word cookies if you're trying to set from a cookie.

Comment: Got it! You rock! Do I still leave the double save or you know an alternative that would be better? I update post & controller info

Comment: Try moving it before the `if @user.save` and rolling only with the single save--just make sure it still works. And accept if that worked :)

Comment: Thanks Todd! I am stuck on making it work for "sign in with facebook". I put in `def self.from_omniauth(auth)`: `if cookies[:challenges_email].present?
user.email = cookies[:challenges_email] else user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com" unless user.email.present? end` but I get the error `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'cookies' for #<Class:0x007f8ebf9f5830>):`. This is beyond the scope of this question, but I'm offering 50 Bounty to solve it over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048080/entered-email-override-securerandom-email :]

Comment: You only have access to cookies in views or controllers but you can write a method and pass it to the model as a param.

Comment: Can you show me with an answer on the other question so I can give you the bounty? I've been struggling with creating a method and/or adding it into the method

Comment: For example I put in users_controller: `def update_facebook_email if cookies[:challenges_email].present? @user.email = cookies[:challenges_email] end end`

Comment: And I put in user.rb: `user.email = user.update_facebook_email`

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the email that is stored in the session to the @user

```
# in users_controller

def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.email = session.delete(:user_email)
end
```

And in the UsersController#create take email from user

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
    email = @user.email
    @user.challenges.create(action: action, email: email)
  end  
end
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the whole UsersController and ChallengesController please.

Comment: In your full ChallengesController there is no session[:user_email] variable assigned in the ChallengesController#create action, as it is in the first example

Comment: I had that in. I put it back in the question as well. Sorry for the confusion. Let me better explain the problem I ran into with your helpful answer. I add user email with challenge form. Got it! Then I move to the signup form and I see the email I put in the challenge form is now there too. Awesome! But then if I signup with "sign in with facebook" button or I take out the email field from the form and then the user is created the user's email = `nil`, but I want it to = whatever email was put in the challenge form. Hope I explained that better :] Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save email to `@user`, you aren't doing it here unless it is part of `user_params`. You assign `email` from `session` but then you don't update `@user`.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
    email = session.delete(:user_email)
    @user.challenges.create(action: action, email: email)
  end  
end
```

I'm not sure why you are passing `email` to `@user.challenges.create` as `challenge_params` does not allow `email`.

I would need to see your `User` model and schema to be sure, but what might work out for you is this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
    email = session.delete(:user_email)
    @user.update_attributes(email: email) unless @user.email
    @user.challenges.create(action: action, email: email)
  end  
end
```

This will only assign `email` to `@user` if `@user` doesn't have an email already.

And, again, I'm not sure if you need to pass `email` to `@user.challenges.create`, although you do seem to have a `default_email` in your `challenge_params`, so if you need that you should change it to `@user.challenges.create(action: action, default_email: email)`.

Comment: Good point. Email is part of users not challenges so it wouldn't make sense to have it in `challenges.create` I suppose. I thought it might go in there because it was created with the challenge in the form. With that said I can't get your answer to work. user.email = nil still upon create.

Comment: Two possibilities are that (1) `email` is not getting set or (2) there is something in your `User` model that is preventing `update_attributes` from updating the email field. You can see if `email` is set by adding `puts "email is: #{email}"` right after `email = session.delete(:user_email)` and checking the output in console, and you'll need to post your `User` model for anyone to comment on option 2.

Comment: And I added user.rb :]

Comment: Hey Joseph. The email field is not updating. But even if it did I'm leaving out the email field. For example if I signup with "sign in with facebook" button or I take out the email field from the form and then the user is created the user's email = nil, but I want it to = whatever email was put in the challenge form. Hope that is clearer. Thanks for your patience!